# Foursquare - get tips from VENUE_ID

Tags: python, foursquare

I tried many times the codes below but the error is always the `venue id`. I am unable to figure out anything wrong with the `venue id`. `4b564bf1f964a520db0928e3` is a random example here.

My codes:

```
tips='https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/tips'

params=dict(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,v='20170801',VENUE_ID='4b564bf1f964a520db0928e3')

resp_tips=requests.get(url=tips, params=params)

data_tips=json.loads(resp_tips.text)

data_tips
```

Error message:

```
{'meta': {'code': 400,
  'errorDetail': 'Value VENUE_ID is invalid for venue id',
  'errorType': 'param_error',
  'requestId': '59e971366a6071382dca9c01'},
 'response': {}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using that API in the wrong way. Try the following code:

```
tips='https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b564bf1f964a520db0928e3/tips'

params=dict(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,v='20170801')

resp_tips=requests.get(url=tips, params=params)

data_tips=json.loads(resp_tips.text)

data_tips
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if I helped you :)